# How to merge multiple dimension array cakephp with two key

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I just using function query() of cakePhp. The query will return array something like :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '11'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '150.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

Now, I want to check if array have the same `cate.date` and `item.code` will merge array (in this case is elements 0,1 of my array). Output something like :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => array (
                'rel_data_category' => '11',
                'price' => '150.000'
            ),
            (int) 1 => array(
                'rel_data_category' => '10',
                'price' => '250.000'
            )
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => array (
                'rel_data_category' => '10'
                'price' => '250.000'
            )
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            (int) 0 => array (
                'rel_data_category' => '10'
                'price' => '250.000'
            )
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    )
)
```

Please help!

Comment: you're not using cakephp query builder for this?

Comment: Yep, I just using `$result = $this->query($query);`

Comment: Can you provide the full query you are using because the array you want can be done by the query itself using `hasmany`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that

First declare a variable which later you will store new merge array data

```
$filter_data = array();
```

then loop your existing array

```
foreach($items as $item) {

    // do somethind
```

then create a function which check if item which same `date` and `code` not yet exist in the new array

```
    // checker
   if (!checkExist($item['cate']['date'], $item['item']['code'])) {
```

Create a variable for temporary data that will append to the new array later

```
    $data = array(
       'cate' => $item['cate'],
       'item' => $item['item']
     );
```

Then create loop again which will append all index item `cate_detail` and `cate_item` who have the same
`date` and `code` from the parent loop

```
   }
}
```

So your code would be like this

```
$items = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '11'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '150.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    )
);

$filter_data = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
   if (!checkExist($item['cate']['date'], $item['item']['code'])) {
     $data = array(
       'cate' => $item['cate'],
       'item' => $item['item']
     );
     foreach($items as $detail) {
       if ($detail['cate']['date'] == $item['cate']['date'] &&
           $detail['item']['code'] == $item['item']['code']) {
         $data['cate_detail'][] = array(
           'rel_data_category' => $detail['cate_detail']['rel_data_category'],
           'price' => $detail['cate_item']['price']
         ); 
       }
     }
     $filter_data[] = $data;
   }
}

function checkExist($date, $code){
   global $filter_data;
   foreach($filter_data as $data) {
     if ($data['cate']['date'] == $date && 
         $data['item']['code'] == $code) {
       return true;
     }
   }
   return false;
}

pr($filter_data);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/712899)

OR

```
$items = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '11'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '150.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-05',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    ),
    (int) 2 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '2'
        )
    ),
    (int) 3 => array(
        'cate' => array(
            'date' => '2016-12-06',
        ),
        'cate_detail' => array(
            'rel_data_category' => '10'
        ),
        'cate_item' => array(
            'price' => '250.000'
        ),
        'item' => array(
            'code' => '1'
        )
    )
);

$filter_data = array();
$exists = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
    $index_key = $item['cate']['date'].'-'.$item['item']['code'];
    if (!isset($exists[$index_key])) {
        $exists[$index_key] = 1;
        $data = array(
            'cate' => $item['cate'],
            'item' => $item['item'],
            'cate_detail' => getItems($item['cate']['date'], $item['item']['code'])
        );
       $filter_data[] = $data;
   }
}

function getItems($date, $code) {
    global $items;
    $data = array();
    foreach($items as $detail) {
       if ($detail['cate']['date'] == $date && $detail['item']['code'] == $code) {
          $data[] = array(
           'rel_data_category' => $detail['cate_detail']['rel_data_category'],
           'price' => $detail['cate_item']['price']
         ); 
       }
    }
    return $data;
}

pr($filter_data);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/712935)

Comment: Thanks for help. It's helpful!